# Can't add label to view

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to add a label to a view, `contactsView`, programmaticly, but for some reason It's not getting added. This is my code, I don't get any error but get nothing.

I have tried call getContacts() in `viewWillAppear` but still nothing

```
class ModuleViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var contactsView: UIView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        getContacts()
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }



    fileprivate func getContacts() {
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 21))
        label.center = CGPoint(x: 160, y: 285)
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.textColor = .black
        label.text = "Test"
        self.contactsView.addSubview(label)     
    }
}
```

Comment: Delete `label.center = CGPoint(x: 160, y: 285)` and see if that helps

Comment: Can't belive it! It worked! Thanks

Comment: Ok I’ll give it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
label.center = CGPoint(x: 160, y: 285)
```

It moves the label out of the contacts view where you can’t see it.